# Dynamic memory allocation in __global__ functions

Tags: cuda, malloc

I have a CC 1.1 card and my program entails me to dynamically allocate arrays in **global** or **device** functions.

These arrays will be created for every thread for execution.

malloc throws up an error and surfing the web tells me that using malloc is illegal for CC less than 2.0.

I wanna ask is there any workaround to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use fixed size memory:

```
__global__ my_kernel(...) {

__shared__ float memory[BLOCK_SIZE];

};
```

dynamic allocation on the GPU is rarely need and can introduce most likely some performance bottleneck. And specially with a compute capability 1.1 you will need to tweak the alignments
of the shared memory to have the best performances and avoid intra-Warp memory contention.

Answer (score 1):

For CC1.1 devices the only workaround is to allocate enough global memory from host with `cudaMalloc` and then divide it between threads.

In most cases just pre-allocating memory from host works pretty well and I've never encountered a task where one *had* to use kernel `malloc` (though sometimes such idea seemed good, it quickly turned out that it was not *that* good to break compatibility with older devices. Also I have suspicions regarding its performance, but I've never run any benchmarks).